# Common Table Expression, why semicolon?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

Usually in `SQL Server` Common Table Expression clause there is semicolon in front of the statement, like this:

```
;WITH OrderedOrders AS --semicolon here
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 50 AND 60
```

Why?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

- To avoid ambiguity because WITH can be used elsewhere
  `..FROM..WITH (NOLOCK)..`
   `RESTORE..WITH MOVE..`
- It's optional to terminate statements with `;` in SQL Server

Put together, the previous statement must be terminated before a WITH/CTE. To avoid errors, most folk use `;WITH` because we don't know what is before the CTE

So

```
DECLARE @foo int;

WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
...;
```

is the same as

```
DECLARE @foo int

;WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
...;
```

The MERGE command has a similar requirement.

Comment: A quick and concise answer, very nice. Mine would take me either half a day long or half a mile page (slightly exaggerated, but not too much). The 'benefits' of speaking English as a second language...

Comment: For newer versions - `The SQL Server documentation indicates that not terminating T-SQL statements with a semicolon is a deprecated feature. This means that the long-term goal is to enforce use of the semicolon in a future version of the product.` - `Miscrosoft SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Fundamentals by Itzik Ben-Gan.`

Comment: Microsoft have deprecated the missing semicolon for over a decade, promising to require it in “a future version”. Good practice is always to use a terminating semicolon, just like all other databases. Among other things, this would remove the need for the quirky leading semicolon in this case.

Comment: @Manngo agree, but sometimes it's just defensive programming especially in a shared dev environment