# What is the "with [alias] as" in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

So I came across the following at work, and I can tell right away what it's **for** but I want to find any documentation for it and can't find anything online!

```
with details as
(
    select *,
    row_number() over (order by CREATED_DATE) as [Row]
    from
    (
        select top 10 * from MyTable
    ) t
)
select *
from details
where [Row] > @lowLimit and [Row] < @highLimit
```

This looks to me like its for paging functionality. However, I don't know exactly what structure I'm looking at within the sql syntax. Does anyone recognize this syntax and can you point me to where I can read more about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  These are used as temporary result sets for single queries.  They are treated by the following query much like a view.  You can do some neat stuff with them, like recursion!

Here's a brief description of their functionality from the link:

- Create a [recursive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) query.
- Substitute for a view when the general use of a view is not required; that is, you do not have to store the definition in metadata.
- Enable grouping by a column that is derived from a scalar subselect, or a function that is either not deterministic or has external access.
- Reference the resulting table multiple times in the same statement.

Regarding semicolons, please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938060/sql-server-common-table-expression-why-semicolon) answer for a really useful tip - why you should always preface CTEs with semicolons.

Comment: I'd be careful about "used as temporary tables" - inline view is a much more accurate and unambiguous description.

Comment: You don't need to put the semicolon in front if you *always* put them where they actually belong - at the end of a statement: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tend to err on the side of caution.  Besides, if someone comes along later and deletes something above it, you're safe.  I know that's not great reasoning, but it happens, like, all the time.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name And also I've been reprimanded on this very site multiple times for posting "broken" code - a CTE solution which was copied and pasted directly into an existing code block with no semi-colons in sight. Particularly here where we're offering code samples for others' consumption, we have absolutely no control over the type of code they'll be mixed with.