# Syntax error: 'with' (with) is not valid input at this position

Tags: mysql, sql

It is said that "MySQL will support CTE's in version 8". But with MySQL server upgraded to 8.0.12, I am still getting this Syntax error for using 'with' clause. The SQL statement I was using is pretty simple

```
With t1 as (select name, price from product) select name from t1
```

Can anyone point out what is the problem with this line of code?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Not sure about MySQl, but in sql-server its recommend to start CTE with semicolon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938060/common-table-expression-why-semicolon

Comment: @Aaron_Geng . . . You probably have some back-compatibility level set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but, all connection, schema and table are created after server was upgraded to 8.0

Answer (score -1):

MySQL doesn't support [common table expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) and `WITH` syntax until version 8.0.1.

Comment: What you say might be true, but Op has installed 8.0.12. I have same problem with 8.0.18.