# Remove missing semi-colon Error from WITH statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
With T As (Select A.TerminationDate,
        B.TerminationApproach,
        B.Date,
        A.UserName,
        A.LastName,
        A.FirstName,
        Case
          When B.Date <= A.TerminationDate Then 0
          Else 1
        End As EvalCheck
      From A 
      Left Join B On B.ChangedUser = A.UserName)
Select T.UserName,
  T.seqnum,
  T.TerminationDate,
  T.TerminationApproach,
  T.Date,
  T.LastName,
  T.FirstName,
  T.EvalCheck
From (Select T.*,
        Row_Number() Over (Partition By T.UserName Order By T.Date) As
        seqnum
      From T) T;
Where T.seqnum = 1
```

And get the following error on my SQL database when trying to execute it:

[image]

Maybe there is a better way to do this query and get rid of the error?

Comment: Is there other code in the batch before the `WITH` statement? If so just prepend a semicolon, i.e.: `; WITH T As....`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common Table Expression, why semicolon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938060/common-table-expression-why-semicolon)

Comment: Although the duplicate answer is a bit out of date, now the recommendation is to terminate all statements with a semicolon rather than just pre-pending with and merge.

Comment: ...Also, `From T) T;
Where T.seqnum = 1` has a misplaced semicolon. Remove that.

Comment: There is no other statement before the WITH statements. The semicolon after the ```T;```was a mistake, but does not solve the problem. Also I have already tried to solve it the way it was described in the other question, but that didn't work either - so the issue remains.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, once you remove the incorrect `;` from your query it works for me.

Comment: I am working on a web-based tool, which has a query builder build inside - this might also cause some problems and that's why I wanted to try a different approach which @Gordon Linoff provided and worked so far!

Comment: @goatw, it seems the tool you are using adds another statement before the CTE that isn't semi-colon terminated (e.g. `SET NOCOUNT ON`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a CTE at all?

```
Select A.TerminationDate, B.TerminationApproach, B.Date,
       A.UserName, A.LastName, A.FirstName,
       (Case When B.Date <= A.TerminationDate Then 0
             Else 1
        End) As EvalCheck
From A Left Join
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by B.ChangedUser order by B.date asc) as seqnum
      from B
     ) B
     On B.ChangedUser = A.UserName and B.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: If I change ```...order by B.date asc) as...``` it works.

Comment: @goatw . . . Yes.  You seem to want the oldest date rather than the newest date.

Answer (score -1):

Because the keyword WITH is overloaded, the position of it in the statement is important. In a CTE it must be first, and this is guaranteed by immediately preceding it with a semicolon.

Comment: Its now the official recommended practice to correctly terminate all statements with a semicolon, not to prepend to `with` and `merge`.