# Why does the cte return the error that it does not exist?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, sql-delete

Here is my code

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT COUNT(CASE name WHEN 'John' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY BlockID ORDER BY Step) AS Johns
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE Johns >= 1;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

It returns me the following error when I run the code in the notebook

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "DELETE"
```

But I can't seem to find any mistake in the query

When I try to do it in online compiler it returns the error that `relation "cte" does not exist`
Maybe this errors can be related?...

Here what I'm trying to do with cte:
My first table:

```
Block_id step name 
1         1    Marie 
1         2    Bob
1         3    John
1         4    Lola
2         1    Alex
2         2    John
2         3    Kate
2         4    Herald
3         1    Alec
3         2    Paul
3         3    Rex
```

As you can see data frame is sorted by block_id and then by step. I want to delete only in one block_id everything after the row where I have name John(the row with John as well). So the desired output would be

```
Block_id step name 
1         1    Marie 
1         2    Bob
2         1    Alex
3         1    Alec
3         2    Paul
3         3    Rex
```

Comment: try to put semicolon before CTE creation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938060/common-table-expression-why-semicolon

Comment: You tagged Postgres but `dbo` is a typical SQL Server schema name. Are you sure Postgres is the DBMS you use?

Comment: Postgresql does not support updatable CTEs.

Comment: @stickybit yes,I'm sure

Comment: @forpas do you know how  is it possible to rewrite the code?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @Austin you mean that the code I wrote will not get me to the expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CTE that returns for each `Block_id` the `step` of the first `John`.
Then join the table to the CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Block_id, MIN(step) step
  FROM tablename
  WHERE name = 'John'
  GROUP BY Block_id
)
DELETE FROM tablename t
USING cte c
WHERE c.Block_id = t.Block_id AND c.step <= t.step
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c2a779c0dd145dd3554ded438ee66bae).

Comment: Thank you very much! It still returns the error in my notebook, but at least works in the compiler)