# Incorrect Syntax near With

Tags: sql, sql-server

No matter where I place my With statement inside the SQL query, the *keyword* in the next line always shows an error, 'Incorrect syntax near *keyword*'. I also tried putting semi-colon.

```
; WITH Commercial_subset AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        PRDID_Clean, Value, [Year] 
    FROM
        Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_commercial]  
    WHERE
        MEASURE = 'Unit Growth Rate'
)
--error appears at truncate
TRUNCATE TABLE Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_3_NR_dup]
```

Example 1:

> [Example 1][1]

Example 2:

> [Example 2][2]

What am I missing?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkfVd.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZRnG.png

My Final code after getting suggestions in the comments,

```html
    --Ensure the correct database is selected for creating the views
    USE Reporting_db_SPKPI
    
    --Create the table where new values will be appended
    Insert into Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_3_NR_dup]
    Select *, Replace(productID,'-','') as ProductID_clean from  Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_3_NR]
    GO
    
    --Create a subset as view which will be used for join later
    Create or Alter View QRY_Commerical_Subset AS
        Select Distinct PRDID_Clean, Value, [Year] From Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_commercial]  where MEASURE = 'Unit Growth Rate'
    Go
    
    --Create a view with distinct list of all SKUs
    CREATE OR ALTER VIEW QRY_RCCP_TEMP AS 
        SELECT 
            PRODUCTID, ROW_NUMBER() Over (ORDER BY ProductID) AS ID 
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                DISTINCT A.ProductID_clean ProductID 
            FROM 
                Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_3_NR_dup] A 
            LEFT JOIN 
                Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.QRY_Commerical_Subset B ON A.ProductID_clean = B.PRDID_Clean 
            WHERE 
                B.PRDID_Clean IS NOT NULL --and A.filename = 'Capacity Planning_INS_Springhill'  --DYNAMIC VARIABLE HERE
                and Cast(A.SnapshotDate as date) = 
                    (SELECT Max(Cast(SnapshotDate as date)) FROM reporting_db_spkpi.dbo.tbl_RCCP_3_NR)
        ) T
    GO
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    
    -- For every product id from the distinct list iterate the following the code
    DECLARE @I INT = 1
    WHILE @I <= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM QRY_RCCP_TEMP)
    BEGIN
    
        DECLARE @PRODUCT NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT PRODUCTID FROM QRY_RCCP_TEMP WHERE ID = @I)
        DROP TABLE Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_3_NR_temp]
        
        --Retrieve last 12 months of value from NR and add it to a temp table in increasing order of their months. These 12 data points will be baseline
        SELECT 
            Top 12 A.*, 
            Case When B.[Value] is Null then 0 else CAST(B.[Value] as float) End GROWTH
        INTO 
            Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_3_NR_temp]
        FROM 
            Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_3_NR_dup] A
        LEFT JOIN 
            --using the view here
            QRY_Commerical_Subset B ON B.PRDID_Clean = A.ProductID_clean AND B.[YEAR] = YEAR(A.[MONTH])+1 
        WHERE 
            A.PRODUCTID= @PRODUCT
            AND Cast(A.SnapshotDate AS DATE) = (SELECT Max(Cast(SnapshotDate AS DATE)) FROM reporting_db_spkpi.dbo.[tbl_RCCP_3_NR_dup])
        Order by 
            [Month] desc
    
        -- Generate 3 years of data
        DECLARE @J INT = 1
        WHILE @J<=3
        BEGIN
            --Calculate next year's value
            UPDATE Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_3_NR_temp]
            SET 
                [Value] = [Value]*(1+ GROWTH), 
                [MONTH] = DATEADD(YEAR,1,[Month]),
                MonthCode= 'F' + CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(MonthCode,2,LEN(MonthCode)) AS INT) + 12 AS NVARCHAR(10))
            
            --Add it to the NR table.
            Insert into Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_3_NR_dup]
                (ProductID, MonthCode, Value, Month, FileName, 
                LastModifiedDate, SnapshotDate, Quarter, IsError, ErrorDescription)
            Select 
                ProductID, MonthCode, Value, Month, FileName, 
                LastModifiedDate, SnapshotDate, Quarter, IsError, ErrorDescription
            from 
                Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_3_NR_temp]
    
            --Update growth rate for next year
            UPDATE Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_3_NR_temp] 
            SET GROWTH = Case When B.[Value] is Null then 0 else CAST(B.[Value] as float) End 
            FROM Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.QRY_Commerical_Subset B 
            WHERE B.PRDID_Clean = ProductID_clean AND [YEAR] = YEAR([MONTH])+1
    
            SET @J=@J+1
        END
        SET @I=@I+1
    END
    DROP VIEW QRY_RCCP_TEMP
    DROP VIEW QRY_Commerical_Subset
```

Comment: `;` is a terminator, not a beginator. Use it to end a statement, not to begin one

Comment: You don't use your Common Table Expression. After you define it you need to use it. Select you want a `SELECT * FROM Commercial_subset;` prior to `TRUNCATE` statement?

Comment: you don't need a CTE here use a *View*

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks!

I am using it inside the while statement which runs more than 2000 times. I want to save define the CTE only once and then refer back to it inside my while statement. Should I still use CTE or should I create a view? Is there any alternate way?

Comment: What is the point of your `with` in the first place? Both `truncate` and `drop` affect the entire table.

Comment: @HoneyBadger https://stackoverflow.com/q/6938060/11683

Comment: *"I am using it inside the while statement which runs more than 2000 times."* Sounds like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). SQL is a *set based* language; there are **very** few times a `WHILE` is the correct solution.

Comment: That doesn't make it *right*, @GSerg . *Not* Terminating statements properly is deprecated. People put it at the front because they don't read the error which clearly states *"**the previous statement must be terminated** with a semicolon."*.

Comment: @Larnu I know that. Still it's a very wide spread technique, as many people do not have a habit of using semicolons at all times.

Comment: Yep, and it's time they got into that habit. @GSerg . :)

Comment: What do you want to use the CTE for (or the View that could replace it)? So far it is just dead code, and incomplete too because there is no SELECT or other statement (e.g. UPDATE or DELETE) that uses it. Because it is incomplete, the whole is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @PeterB Oh, I have just shared a small snippet from code. 


GSerg, Larnu Yes, semicolons. I use it in my codes to terminate all statement. I had added it in the beginning because I thought maybe it could solve the issue I was facing as mentioned in one of the posts.

I understood now that CTE's need to be used in Select statement immediately after they are created. 

I am going to create a view (to get a subset of the dataset) and use it inside my while statement. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Using 3-part names is a bad habit. If your code starts with `USE Reporting_db_SPKPI`, there is no good reason to add that same database name to every object reference. Imagine how much extra confusion and work you have created by doing this if someone changes that USE statement and then assumes that the query produces data for the new database.

Comment: @SMor Thats a valid point. I am still learning. Thanks for adding :)

Comment: Also, my code is taking longer to run than I think it should. I have received lots of good suggestions over this post. Can somebody point me out some more tips/optimized ways of writing the above SQL query or any part of it?

Comment: @AakashJaiswal with respect to performance, that is really another question. But you are looping, twice. Sql is best at set processing, not in row-by-agonizing-row. Not only that, but in your first loop you're dropping and creating a table for every row. This is hugely inefficient. Rewrite your loops to use set-based logic, and you'll have much better performance.

Comment: @HoneyBadger. Thank you for your advice. Set based. Got it! I'll try that. If convenient can you write that piece for me just so that I know I am following the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

The `WITH` is a [Common Table Expression](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cte-in-sql/), aka CTE.

And a CTE is like a template for a sub-query.

For example this join of the same sub-query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select distinct bar 
    from table1
    where foo = 'baz'
) AS foo1
JOIN (
    select distinct bar 
    from table1
    where foo = 'baz'
) AS foo2
  ON foo1.bar > foo2.bar
```

Can be written as

```
WITH CTE_FOO AS (
  select distinct bar 
  from table1 
  where foo = 'baz' 
) 
SELECT *
FROM CTE_FOO AS foo1
JOIN CTE_FOO AS foo2
  ON foo1.bar > foo2.bar
```

It's meant to be used with a `SELECT`.
Not with a `TRUNCATE TABLE` or `DROP TABLE`.
*(It can be used with an UPDATE though)*

As such, treat the TRUNCATE as a seperate statement.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_3_NR_dup];

WITH Commercial_subset AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        PRDID_Clean, Value, [Year] 
    FROM
        Reporting_db_SPKPI.DBO.[tbl_RCCP_commercial]  
    WHERE
        MEASURE = 'Unit Growth Rate'
)
SELECT *
FROM Commercial_subset;
```

*Btw, the reason why many write a CTE with a leading `;` is because the WITH clause raises an error if the previous statement wasn't ended with a `;`.  It's just a small trick to avoid that error.*